# Image not being rendered as soon as I add it to a page

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am a newbie in Windows phone app development. On one of my pages I have a button that does some substantial amount of work. So when I press the button the screen freezes and then resumes when all the work is done. Now I wanted to show some waiting image or page to be shown during this while.

So I created and destroyed an image on top on the page at the start and end of button click action respectively but it still freezes and the screen renders only after all the work is done making it indifferent. I am using Silverlite C#.

Comment: Your second para is not so clear. share the code of the Button_click event handler, so that it wil be easy to identify your problem

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to push the heavy work onto a background thread. What's currently happening is that the work is being done on the UI thread, so it 'freezes' since the UI thread is waiting for the work to be done. There are various ways you can push the work to a background thread. One way would be to use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4852et58%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

A simple example, which doesn't include things like reporting when the work is done, would look like this

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(BW_DoWork);
bw.RunWorkerAsync();

private void BW_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //Your heavy work code
}
```

Important thing to remember when you work on a background thread, is that if you want to change anything on the UI, you need to marshal the data to the UI thread and update it there. You can do that like this:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
       myTextBlockExample.Text = "Changing the UI";           
}
```

If you tried to change the `TextBlock` without the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` method, you'll get a `Invalid Cross-Thread Access` error. If you see that error in WP development, it's likely that you're trying to update a UI element from a non-UI thread.

You can put your code that displays the loading image before calling `bw.RunWorkerAsync`.